# React JS: backend web application framework

Tags: model-view-controller, web-applications, frameworks, reactjs, reactjs-flux

React's website states:

> Lots of people use React as the V in MVC.

From this, I am inferring that React does not play the "M" and the "C" roles in MVC.

If this is correct, it means one cannot build an entire web application solely with React JS.

Then, how?

- Does React require a complete MVC framework for the backend, such as Rails or Laravel?
- Can React simply pull data from a backend where a framework, such as Rails or Laravel, would be setup as a web API?
- Does React not need any of this and works in a totally different way (in other words: am I completely missing the point)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MVC is just a term for structuring data flow in an application.
You do not need MVC to build an application, even if it might help.

What React does is that it specializes in building isolated components - where the data flows in a single direction(the von neumann model of computing).

This is very nice because you can build an application with the premise that everything is always rerendered when data is changed, thus avoiding hard to read "two way bindings".
The thing is that it's very inefficient to rerender every view when some minor data is altered, but Reacts "Shadow DOM" optimizes this process, and makes efficient rerenders.

But React does not care where it gets data from. You could build a backend with nodejs/php/ruby or whatever you want. How you communicate and send data between the frontend and the backend is also left up to you. You could use jquery/socketio/superagent or whatever you want.

You can also combine React with any other framework, or just skip frameworks all together and fetch the data directly from a react component.

Facebook, the creators of React, have their way or organising projects called flux, which plays well with react(even if it is not needed). 
https://github.com/facebook/flux

Comment: Thanks, that is pretty clear and makes a lot of sense. I was also wondering whether Facebook was advocating a particular backend solution over another, but could not find an answer to that. From what you say, they don't?

Comment: They do not advocate any specific solution, and they probably never will. 
They use flux as a replacment for MVC, because it works well for them. However, your use case and your challenges are probably not the same as facebooks. Thus, you should use a backend solution and a frontend design-pattern that you feel comfortable with. 


However if you are interested in facebooks ideas for backend solutions, they do however have some interesting projects going on - like Relay(http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/02/20/introducing-relay-and-graphql.html).